# Enable the use of SSI

Tags: apache, web, dreamweaver

Using HostGator, I can't seem to get SSI to work on my server.  I'm using Dreamweaver to build the site and the everything works just fine in the preview.  But when I actually upload the pages to my server, any elements that are includes files don't appear.  Does anyone know how I can enable SSI on my web server?

Comment: What file types are your pages? SSI requires SHTML, so make sure you're using SHTML files.  If you're using PHP, use `<?php include(String filename); ?>

Comment: I've tried using both shtml and php, neither seem to work.  I have also tried editing the .htaccess to allow html files to be used with SSI but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using for the SSI?

Comment: for the included code it's `<!-- Footer Menu -->
<div class="foot-container">
 <div class="footer"> 
   <div class="foot-one footerlink-one">   
  <a href="Library/index.html">Home</a><br />
  <a href="Library/about.html">About Us</a><br />
  <a href="Library/contact.html">Contact Us</a><br />
   </div>
   
   <div class="foot-one footerlink-one">   
  <a href="Library/products/index.html">Products</a><br />
  <div class="foot-two footerlink-two">   
   <a href="Library/products/accesscontrol.html">Access Control</a><br />
  </div>
   </div>
   
 </div>
</div>`

Comment: How are you attempting to "access" the code?

(ex. `<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->`)

Comment: `<!-- #include file= "includes/footer.inc"-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last comment gave me the information I need.  The issue is that the file is not in the same directory as the file you're trying to add the footer.inc file to.  Try this code:

```
<!--#include virtual= "includes/footer.inc" -->
```

when using the `file=` parameter, the file you're including must be in the same directory. If the file you're including is *not* in the same directory, then you will have to use `virtual`. See this page for more information: [SSI: The Include Command](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341).

And here, from the source, is pretty much the rule of thumb: Use `file=` when the included file is within the same directory as the page that wants it. Use `virtual=` when it isn't.

**EDIT:** I think I got it now. Copy and paste the above code and it should work for you. Make sure you follow these guideline: after `<!--`, there is no space between the last `-` and `#`. Additionally, there is a space between the closing `"` and the first `-`. These rules must be adhered to.  You can view more information here: [Server Side Includes Not Working](http://www.coranto.org/wiki/index.php/Troubleshooting/SSIproblem)

Comment: I used the code you posted, but still nothing.  Everything works fine in Dreamweaver but when it's uploaded to the server the footer still doesn't appear.

Comment: Toss this line in a SHTML file and see what comes up: `<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->`

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean.  That just makes the date and time appear.  `Friday, 24-Jan-2014 20:19:30 CST`

Comment: I just wanted to make sure SSI was enabled on your browser.  I have modified my answer, it should work now (I tested it on my web server, which is ran through a webhost that is ran by the same company that runs HostGator)

Comment: Ah, there we go.  The space in-between the `<!--` and the `#include` was the problem.  And the guide you linked to was very helpful; thanks.